# "Sample DB" for Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

MySQL has this [Sample Sakila DB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-history.html) where we can start playing around with bunch of data already for our application, how about for Google App Engine/GAEJ is there something like this for the datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started recently to experiment with the Google App Engine and I was confronted with the same question. I was interested in a REST based app engine backbone which I could easily load/unload with data but couldn't  find something to play around.

So I started to build up two projects on github which supports me in such kind of work.

[clb-appEngineTemplate](https://github.com/talfco/clb-appEngineTemplate) is a skeleton application for a Google App Engine Jave REST backend. It provides some sample code for a standardized REST API based persistency layer on Business Object level and can be easily extended (using Objectify and GSON).

[clb-test](https://github.com/talfco/clb-test) which is a utility class which allows to load Test Data from Excel CSV file into your Google App Engine REST backend.

Both projects are maven based and allow me easily to define data objects which I can upload into the App Engine. Mainly I'm run them against the local test server, which serves me for initial testing.

I just released a first version and will incrementally extend over the next weeks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no sample DB for GAE, probably because datastore write operations are expensive. There are demos bundled with GAE SDK. If you are using Eclipse you can [import](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_sampleapps) the samples to your workspace. Some of them involve datastore so you can run the application and add data yourself.

Another way is to use [bulkloader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) to upload data at once using CSV files. But you can quickly run out of free quota for datastore writes.